# Execute a php page every 24 hours

Tags: php, database, parsing, dom

I have a database and i must update it parsing some html pages every 24 hours and putting these new informarmations inside. The parse for the html pages is in a php file and i should execute this code every 24 hours. Is there a way to do it? Are there some alternatives?

Comment: cron - *nix, nncron or task scheduler - windows

Comment: Yep but on windows you'll have to use the task scheduler to run a batch file that will run your script I think... Or maybe you'll be able to run the PHP directly but it depends how and where you installed PHP

Comment: Can you post your operating system and the location of your php file so we can give you direction instructions.  Cron is the way to go if you are on linux, but it needs to be formatted precisely to get it done right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you're using LINUX**

Use Cron Jobs

```
# run the script at 4:30am every day
30 4 * * * lynx -dump http://www.yourwebsite.com/myscript.php
```

If you're PHP script is CLI suited use instead

```
30 4 * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/me/myscript.php
```

**If you're using WINDOWS**

Use sheduled task http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ie/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7

If you're using XAMP

```
C:\xampp\php\php.exe -f c:/xampp/htdocs/myscript.php
```

Answer (score 1):

**LINUX**

On a linux server you can schedule tasks using Cron. It is driven by a crontab file, a configuration file that specifies shell commands to run periodically on a given schedule

Here is the [man page of Crontab](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab%205).

Here are some examples from the documentation:

```
   # run five minutes after midnight, every day
   5 0 * * *       $HOME/bin/daily.job >> $HOME/tmp/out 2>&1
   # run at 2:15pm on the first of every month -- output mailed to paul
   15 14 1 * *     $HOME/bin/monthly
   # run at 10 pm on weekdays, annoy Joe
   0 22 * * 1-5    mail -s "It's 10pm" joe%Joe,%%Where are your kids?%
   23 0-23/2 * * * echo "run 23 minutes after midn, 2am, 4am ..., everyday"
   5 4 * * sun     echo "run at 5 after 4 every sunday"
```

To run your script every day at 1:30am you would do:

```
  crontab -e
```

and then add:

```
  30 1 * * * /path/Of/PHP /path/Of/Your/Script.php
```

**WINDOWS**

On windows use Task Scheduler.

Here is the [documentation](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7).

Comment: It is called cron. Crontab (cron table) is just a file with list of tasks.